# How would you verify that two colored planar graphs are isomorphic?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

What is an algorithm to deduce whether two colored planar graphs are isomorphic? I am aware that isomorphism is a hard problem for graphs in general, however, according to wikipedia it is possible to solve if the graphs are planar.

The application of this algorithm will be to deduce whether two planar molecules, represented with some graph-based datastructure, are the same (isomorphic). Since nodes represent atoms, the coloring of the graph is simply the type of atom (Hydrogen, Carbon, Nitrogen etc).

Comment: I think this fits one of the computer science stack exchanges better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that a node in one graph can only map through a graph isomorphism to a node in an another graph if the two nodes have the same degree.

You can create a small planar graph with a node of any desired degree by putting that node in the center, putting nodes to make up the degree around it, and creating links between the central node and all the other nodes. By shrinking this down as small as you like, you can arrange to add this, as a subgraph, to any node of a given planar graph, without making it non-planar.

Given a planar graph with coloured nodes, find the maximum degree of any node in it, and create little subgraphs of degrees above this to serve as colour markings: give each colour its own degree and link a separate little subgraph of that degree to each node of that colour.

Now solve the planar graph isomorphism on this augmented graph and you have a solution for the original graph. Similarly, any solution for the original graph can easily be turned into a solution for the augmented graph.

Answer (score 1):

**Try NetworkX Library**

You haven't mentioned what programming language you're interested in but the [NetworkX library](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) for python has multiple approaches for finding isomorphisms. You might want to look at their [implementation of the VF2 algorithm](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.isomorphism.vf2.html) which includes the ability to subclass and define a "semantic" evaluation which would address the atomic-element matching in your problem. The semantic evaluation is already in the algorithm but with a placeholder function that always returns true, so if you replace the placeholder function with one that evaluates the atomic element the algorithm class may work for you otherwise unmodified.

Alternately you can run the algorithm to match shape and then look at the `GM.mapping` parameter (see implementation link) and compare the elements at the equivalent nodes in each isomorphism for elemental equivalence.

If you are looking for the general algorithm instead of a programming library, try this paper ([PDF here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.5342&rep=rep1&type=pdf), no paywall):

***L. P. Cordella, P. Foggia, C. Sansone, M. Vento, “An Improved
Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs”, 3rd IAPR-TC15 Workshop on Graph-based Representations in Pattern Recognition, Cuen, pp. 149-159, 2001***

Update Nov 2015: Apparently a professor has figured out how to do this in sub-NP time! He hasn't published yet, but [here's a starter link](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2521) for those into the pure math.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](http://cs.brown.edu/sites/jgaa/accepted/2004/KuklukHolderCook2004.8.3.pdf) (which I found on citeseer) seems useful, since it includes both the (outline of) an algorithm and some probably useful benchmark comparisons with other algorithms, for which it also provides bibliographic references. However, I suspect that the size of the problems you're looking at would not be in the profile where the Kukluk et al. graph mapper wins over other algorithms.

General purpose planar graph isomorphism algorithms don't even attempt to take advantage of node "colour" (I would have said labels, since I usually think of colours applying to edges, but that's not really important), and you may well be able to do better by using the additional information. But certainly if there is not uncoloured/unlabelled isomorphism then there cannot be a coloured/labelled one. Unfortunately, being able to construct a single isomorphism isn't enough to decide whether or not there is an isomorphism with colours/labels; you need to try all possible isomorphisms. I think there's enough information left from the decomposition to simplify this search, but I'm not sure; it seems like an interesting problem.

I understand that you have a particular programming problem in mind, and that does (and should) bias your search for a solution. So feel free to ignore the following point: coloured/labelled isomorphism cannot be theoretically easier than general isomorphism, because it is valid for all the nodes to have the same colour/label. (That's totally irrelevant to your environment, I think, since none of your target molecules will consist of a single element, right?)